# setInterval/setTimeOut function with for loop showing unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
    display_para(i);
};

function display_para(i){

    setInterval(function(){
        console.log(i);

        //Stuff to be done

    }, 1500 + i * 2000);
};


Expected result:
0 1 2 ; 0 1 2; 0 1 2 and so on.
```

Whereas it is showing different output as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I could not understand where am I going wrong.

Comment: every 1.5 seconds, 0 will be output. every 3.5 seconds a 1, and every 5.5 seconds a 2 ... the timings are independent of each other (i.e. one interval doesn't wait for another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because how you have setup the timers, the `0` call will execute in every 1500ms, `1` call in every 3500ms and `2` call in every 5500ms.

One solution is to use a single `inteval` where based on a counter you decide the value to be printed like

```js
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  display_para(i);
  if (++i > 2) {
    i = 0;
  }
}, 1500);

function display_para(i) {
  document.body.innerHTML += i + '<br />'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need this:

```js
 var i = -1;

 setInterval(function() {
   i = i > 1 ? 0 : ++i;
   console.log(i);
 }, 1500)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect `0 1 2` in a sequence because there are three `setInterval()` running simultaneously in a different time interval. It's only possible if time interval is uniform like:

```
function display_para(i) {
        setInterval(function () {
            console.log(i);
        }, 200);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop expands to:

```
display_para(0);
display_para(1);
display_para(2);
```

The setInterval timers created:

```
log 0 every 1500 ms
log 1 every 3500 ms
log 2 every 5500 ms
```

So

```
timer 0 fires at: 1500   3000   4500  6000  7500 
timer 1 fires at:           3500        7000
timer 2 fires at:                 5500
```

giving

```
Expected result:   0     0  1   0 2   0 1   0
```